# Remove specific items from Exchange 2013 users cached contacts (auto complete)

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have a single c-level user who has several cached contacts with an old domain address. Is there a simple way (powershell or otherwise) to remove all address with this domain from his cached (auto complete) contacts?

Answer (score 0):

There is not simple way to do this as far as I know. Office <-2007 and Office 2013-> stores this cache in the user profile and not centrally. You could either clear the whole cache in options (or by running `Outlook.exe /CleanAutoCompleteCache`) or he could remove them one by one manually:

1. Open a new mail
2. Write parts of the address
3. Click "X" to the right of the suggested auto-complete name that pops up.

Comment: I believe Exchange 2010 forward stores cached contacts on the server and I know 2013 does. Going through manually would be a real pain but I suppose it is doable for a c-level employee. I'm going to hold out for a little bit longer and hope that someone proposes a more automated method.

Comment: Outlook 2010 had a folder called suggested contacts, but I think that disappeared again in 2013 so it went back to local cache only.